# How does burn detect that it needs to uninstall itself?

Tags: .net, wix, wix3.7, bootstrapper, burn

Burn, the WiX bootstrapper application, when run, does a check to determine if it requires an uninstall. Say I have the following bundle `Chain`:

```
<ExePackage Permanent="yes" ...
<MsiPackage Visible="yes" DisplayInternalUI="yes" ...
```

How does burn determine whether or not it should present a dialog to uninstall itself? How does it know that it, the bootstrapper itself, is installed or not? After I run the bootstrapper and have installed the bundle, if I uninstall the MsiPackage from Programs and Features, and then run my bootstrapper again, it will show an Uninstall option...despite the fact that all non-permanent packages have been removed. Clearly, it must have left something behind to detect that just the bootstrapper was installed at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Got it, it checks for a registry key in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{The GUID for this Particular Installation}` or in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{The GUID for this Particular Installation}`.

To find out what `{The GUID for this Particular Installation}` is for your bootstrapper, look for an element with a property of `BundleUpgradeCode` (`REG_MULTI_SZ`) that is equal to the upgrade code of your package.

Comment: Also interesting to note...the "burn" bootstrapper detects whether or not a reboot is pending by checking the existence of a key at this path: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\("Wow6432Node\" if you have an x86 installer on an x64 machine)Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{The GUID for this Particular Installation}.RebootRequired`